# How to delete some XML tags in a GET request

Tags: java, xml, rest, jpa, jaxb

I want to print something like this on the browser:

```
<measureTypes>
    <measureType>weight</measureType>
    <measureType>height</measureType>
    <measureType>steps</measureType>
    <measureType>bloodpressure</measureType>
</measureTypes>
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
<measureDefinitions>
    <measureDefinition>
        <measureName>weight</measureName>
    </measureDefinition>
    <measureDefinition>
        <measureName>height</measureName>
    </measureDefinition>
    <measureDefinition>
        <measureName>steps</measureName>
    </measureDefinition>
    <measureDefinition>
        <measureName>blood pressure</measureName>
    </measureDefinition>
    <measureDefinition>
        <measureName>heart rate</measureName>
    </measureDefinition>
    <measureDefinition>
        <measureName>bmi</measureName>
    </measureDefinition>
</measureDefinitions>
```

Here is my code from the Model class:

```
@NamedQuery(name="MeasureDefinition.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM MeasureDefinition m")
public static List<MeasureDefinition> getAll() {
    EntityManager em = LifeCoachDao.instance.createEntityManager();

    List<MeasureDefinition> list = em.createNamedQuery("MeasureDefinition.findAll",                    MeasureDefinition.class).getResultList();
    LifeCoachDao.instance.closeConnections(em);
    return list;
}
```

Here is the code from the Resource class (this is where I print the output):

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML,  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ,  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<MeasureDefinition> getMeasuresTypes() {
    EntityManager em = LifeCoachDao.instance.createEntityManager();
    System.out.println("Getting list of measures...");
    List<MeasureDefinition> measures = MeasureDefinition.getAll();
    System.out.println("Measures " + measures);
    System.out.println("Size of the list " + measures.size());
    return measures;
}
```

Therefore my question is this: how can I remove the `<measureDefinition>` from the output? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can u post `MeasureDefinition.findAll` query and `MeasureDefinition` bean?

Comment: I've already posted it. It is defined in @NamedQuery

Comment: Easiest way would be to not send the list of MeasureDefinition but a single MeasureDefinition, then make measureName attribue a list of string. That would give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to create a customer wrapper around that list, and then do the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "measureTypes")
public class MessageDefinitionResult {

    @XmlElement(name = "measureType")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MeasureDefinitionXmlAdapter.class)
    private List<MeasureDefinition> measureDefinitions;

    public MessageDefinitionResult(final List<MeasureDefinition> measureDefinitions) {
        this.measureDefinitions = measureDefinitions;
    }

    public MessageDefinitionResult() { }

    public List<MeasureDefinition> getMeasureDefinitions() {
        return measureDefinitions;
    }

    public static final class MeasureDefinitionXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, MeasureDefinition> {

        @Override
        public MeasureDefinition unmarshal(final String v) throws Exception {
            return null; // or whatever
        }

        @Override
        public String marshal(final MeasureDefinition v) throws Exception {
            return v.getName();
        }
    }

}
```

....

```
package de.zalando.shop.frontend.springmvc.controller.user.account;

/**
 * @author  mochieng (marembo.isaiah.ochieng@zalando.de)
 * @since   Nov 13, 2015
 */
public class MeasureDefinition {

    private String name;

    private String value;

    private String moreValuesAndProperties;

    public MeasureDefinition(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public MeasureDefinition(final String name, final String value, final String moreValuesAndProperties) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.moreValuesAndProperties = moreValuesAndProperties;
    }

    public MeasureDefinition() { }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getMoreValuesAndProperties() {
        return moreValuesAndProperties;
    }

}
```